# Convert string to with two decimals and then add both

Tags: javascript

I have two variables which are string and I convert them to float. But when I want to add both and get a result, they both get concatenated.

This is how I do it:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    var CantVendida='2.00';
    var CantidadBonificacion='1.00';
    var CantidadVenBon=parseFloat(CantVendida).toFixed(2)+parseFloat(CantidadBonificacion).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = CantidadVenBon;
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: toFixed converts it back to string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.toFixed(2)` on the result rather than the operands.

If you use `.toFixed(2)` on the operands, you're actually converting them to strings before the `+` operation takes place.  That's why you're getting string concatenation instead of mathematical addition in your version.

See below.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    var CantVendida='2.00';
    var CantidadBonificacion='1.00';
    var CantidadVenBon=parseFloat(CantVendida)+parseFloat(CantidadBonificacion);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = CantidadVenBon.toFixed(2);
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### This question is about *type conversions*.

[This page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp) shows how to converting data types.

In your question, we need to use `Number()` built in function to convert *String* to *Number*.

```
let stringNumberOne = "2.3"; // typeof(stringNumberOne) => "string"
let stringNumberTwo = "3.3"; // typeof(stringNumberTwo) => "string"
let stringAddition = stringNumberOne + stringNumberTwo; // Result: "2.33.3"

let convertedStringNumberOne = Number(stringNumberOne); // typeof(convertedStringNumberOne) => "number"
let convertedStringNumberTwo = Number(stringNumberTwo); // typeof(convertedStringNumberTwo) => "number"
let convertedStringAddition = convertedStringNumberOne + convertedStringNumberTwo; // Result: 5.6
```